Laravel: How can I optimize my job posting form in Laravel with Blade components? And have it load faster? FOUC problem
I'm working on a job posting form in Laravel using Blade components and Tailwind CSS. The form includes various input fields for job details like title, description, location, type, etc. I'm concerned about a few aspects and would appreciate some advice:
FOUC Prevention: I'm using the @vite directive to include CSS and JS files. Is there a better approach to prevent the Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC)?
Form Validation: I’m handling error messages with the @error directive, but I want to make sure the error messages are correctly displayed next to each field. How can I ensure consistent error handling within my Blade components?
JavaScript Spinner: I've implemented a spinner that should appear when the form is submitted. However, I'm not sure if my current method is the most efficient. What’s the best practice for managing a submit button spinner and text visibility?
Real-Time Validation: I want to add real-time feedback on form fields, like highlighting missing required fields. What’s the best approach to implement this using Laravel and JavaScript?
Here’s the relevant code snippet:
I know the code is long, but I'll divide it:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Create Job Post</title>


    {{-- <!-- Hide content until CSS is fully loaded --> to prevent FOUC (FLASH OF UNSTYLED CONTENT) --}}
    <noscript>
    <style>

    </style>
</noscript>

    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>

<body class="flex items-start justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-50">

    <div class="w-full max-w-4xl p-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
        <h1 class="mb-4 text-2xl font-bold text-pink-600">Create a Job Post</h1>
        <p class="mb-6 text-gray-700">Provide the necessary details to create a job posting that attracts the right
            candidates.</p>
        <form action="{{ route('job-listings.store') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="flex items-start justify-between mb-4">
                <button type="reset" class="px-4 py-2 text-white bg-gray-600 rounded">Reset Form</button>
            </div>


            <!-- First Row: Job Title and Job Location -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-2">
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.input-field label="Job Title" type="text" id="job_title" for="job_title"
                        placeholder="Enter job title" />
                    @error('job_title')
                        <span class="text-sm text-red-500" aria-live="polite">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.select name="location" label="Job Location" id="job_location">
                        @foreach ($counties as $county)
                            <option value="{{ $county['geonameId'] }}">{{ $county['name'] }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        @error('job_location')
                            <span class="text-sm text-red-500" aria-live="polite">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </x-joblistings.select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Third Row: Job Description -->
            <div>
                <x-joblistings.text-area label="Job Description" for="job_description" placeholder="Describe Job Role"
                    id="job_description">

                </x-joblistings.text-area>
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <x-joblistings.input-field label="Job Category" for="job_category"
                        placeholder="Category or industry the job belongs to" id="job_category" />
                    <small class="text-gray-500">Start typing to see suggestions...</small>

                </div>

            </div>


            <!-- Second Row: Job Type and Job Status -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 mt-4 md:grid-cols-2">
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.select name="type" label="Job Type" id="job_type">
                        <option value="full-time">Full-Time</option>
                        <option value="part-time">Part-Time</option>
                        <option value="contract">Contract</option>
                    </x-joblistings.select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.select name="status" label="Job Status" id="job_status">
                        <option value="open">Open</option>
                        <option value="closed">Closed</option>
                        <option value="filled">Filled</option>
                    </x-joblistings.select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.input-field label="Job Min Salary" id="job_min_salary" type="number"
                        for="job_min_salary" placeholder="What is the Minimum salary?(optional)">
                        <small class="text-gray-500">Please enter the minimum expected salary in KSH.</small>
                    </x-joblistings.input-field>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.input-field label="Job Max Salary" id="job_max_salary" type="number"
                        for="job_max_salary" placeholder="What is the Maximum salary?(optional)">
                        <small class="text-gray-500">Please enter the minimum expected salary in KSH.</small>
                    </x-joblistings.input-field>
                </div>
            </div>




            <!-- Fourth Row: Job Experience and Application Deadline -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 mt-4 md:grid-cols-2">
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.input-field label="Job Experience" id="job_experience" type="text"
                        for="job_experience" placeholder="Enter required experience level">
                        <small class="text-gray-500">Example: 3-5 years of experience in software development.</small>
                        @error('job_experience')
                            <span class="text-sm text-red-500" aria-live="polite">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </x-joblistings.input-field>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.input-field label="Application Deadline" id="application_deadline" type="date"
                        for="application_deadline" placeholder="Select application deadline">
                        @error('application_deadline')
                            <span class="text-sm text-red-500" aria-live="polite">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </x-joblistings.input-field>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Fifth Row: Job Requirements and Job Skills -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 mt-4 md:grid-cols-2">
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.text-area label="Job Requirements" id="job_requirements" for="job_requirements"
                        placeholder="List the job requirements"></x-joblistings.text-area>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="job_skills" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Job Skills</label>
                    <div id="skills-container">
                        <div class="flex items-center gap-2 mt-1">
                            <input type="text" name="job_skills[]" id="job_skills"
                                class="block w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm"
                                placeholder="Enter a job skill">
                            <!-- Delete button for the initial skill -->
                            <button type="button" class="px-2 py-1 text-white bg-red-600 rounded"
                                onclick="removeSkill(this)">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" onclick="addSkill()"
                        class="px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-white bg-pink-600 rounded">Add More Skills</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Sixth Row: Job Benefits and Application Instructions -->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 mt-4 md:grid-cols-2">
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.text-area label="Job Benefits" id="job_benefits" for="job_benefits"
                        placeholder="List the job benefits (optional)"></x-joblistings.text-area>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-joblistings.text-area label="Application Instructions" id="application_instructions"
                        for="application_instructions"
                        placeholder="Provide any specific instructions for applying (optional)"></x-joblistings.text-area>
                </div>
            </div>



            <!-- Submit Button -->

            <x-joblistings.button type="submit" id="submit-btn">
                <span id="submit-text">Create Job</span>
                <span id="submit-spinner" class="hidden">
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5 text-white animate-spin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <circle class="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="currentColor"
                            stroke-width="4"></circle>
                        <path class="opacity-75" fill="currentColor"
                            d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8V0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12h4zm2 5.291A7.962 7.962 0 014 12H0c0 2.21.897 4.21 2.342 5.658l1.658-1.367z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </span>
            </x-joblistings.button>

        </form>
    </div>

To try and restore visibility once the css is loaded
@vite('resources/js/joblisting.js')



    <script>
        // <!-- Restore visibility once the CSS is fully loaded -->
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.documentElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.documentElement.style.opacity = '1';
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>

This is my JS
// Function to add skill input fields
        function addSkill() {
            const container = document.getElementById('skills-container');
            const skillDiv = document.createElement('div');
            skillDiv.className = 'flex items-center gap-2 mt-1';

            const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'text';
            input.name = 'job_skills[]';
            input.className = 'block w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm';
            input.placeholder = 'Enter another job skill';

            const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            deleteButton.type = 'button';
            deleteButton.className = 'px-2 py-1 text-white bg-red-600 rounded';
            deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
            deleteButton.onclick = function() {
                removeSkill(deleteButton);
            };

            skillDiv.appendChild(input);
            skillDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);
            container.appendChild(skillDiv);
        }

        // Function to remove a skill input field
        function removeSkill(button) {
            const skillDiv = button.parentElement;
            skillDiv.remove();
        }

        // Real-time validation
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const form = document.querySelector('form');
            const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[required], textarea[required], select[required]');

            inputs.forEach(input => {
                input.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    if (this.checkValidity()) {
                        this.classList.remove('border-red-500');
                        this.classList.add('border-green-500');
                    } else {
                        this.classList.remove('border-green-500');
                        this.classList.add('border-red-500');
                    }
                });
            });

            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                let valid = true;
                inputs.forEach(input => {
                    if (!input.checkValidity()) {
                        valid = false;
                        input.classList.add('border-red-500');
                    }
                });

                if (!valid) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('Please fill out the required fields.');
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('submit-text').classList.add('hidden');
                    document.getElementById('submit-spinner').classList.remove('hidden');
                }
            });

            form.addEventListener('reset', function(e) {
                if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?")) {
                    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from resetting if the user cancels
                } else {
                    // Action to perform when user confirms the reset
                    console.log('Form has been reset.');
                    // You can add any other action you want to perform here
                }
            });
        });

AND APP.CSS


@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
}




I’d appreciate any advice or best practices to improve the performance, usability, and accessibility of this form. Thanks in advance!

real time validation is probably better handled by the official precognition package https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/precognition
